# Is SizeThatFits call necessary for a fixed width and height UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

If I set my UILabel frame to a fixed width, number of lines to 1 and set

```
lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
```

Should I still call `sizeThatFits` to reframe the UILabel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you set fix height and width constraint then your label's size will not change. It will be fix as constant of your constraints. so, `sizeThatFits` has no meaning in that case!!